# How to Pass a cv::Mat across a network?

Tags: c++, opencv, network-programming

What is the best way to pass a cv::Mat across a Network (TCP/UDP) and reconstruct it on the server? Any ideas? e.g. Put it in a string or any specific data-structure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The same way you use to transfer any other kind of data](http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/output/html/singlepage/bgnet.html#serialization).

It's also worth checking this post: [Passing a structure through Sockets in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1577161/passing-a-structure-through-sockets-in-c)