# How to pass the `type` of `cv::Mat` to a function?

Tags: c++, opencv, realsense

As per [`cv::Mat` Class Reference](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d3/d63/classcv_1_1Mat.html), one of the constructor is:

```
    Mat (int rows, int cols, int type, void *data, size_t step=AUTO_STEP)
```

Now, I have [`rs2::frame`](https://intelrealsense.github.io/librealsense/doxygen/classrs2_1_1frame.html) and I want to convert them to `cv::Mat`. So, I have defined one function, and in the conversion, I want to specify the [`cv::Mat::type`](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d3/d63/classcv_1_1Mat.html#af2d2652e552d7de635988f18a84b53e5) i.e. whether the output `cv::Mat` should be of type `CV_8SC1` or `CV_16SC1` or so on.

As of now, my function is something like this:

```
cv::Mat foo(rs2::frame fr, std::string mat_type) {
    .
    .
    .
}
```

For the `mat_type`, as shown above, I'm passing the string i.e. `"CV_8SC1"`, `"CV_16SC1"`, etc and in the function body, I'm manually comparing the strings:

```
    .
    .
    if(mat_type == "CV_8SC1") {
        return cv::Mat(width, height, CV_8SC1, ...);
    } else if ...
    .
    .
    .
    else {
        
    }
```

However, this is not very efficient, right? Let say, in the future, if I need another type of `cv::Mat` then I have to update the function by adding a new condition to `if... else...`  statements.

So, how can I avoid this and do something else which is more efficient? I mean, is there any way to pass the `cv::Mat::type` directly rather than passing an equivalent string(s) and then comparing in the function body?

*Just to clarify in advance:* my question is different from these questions:

1. What is the best practise for passing cv::Mats around - [link](https://answers.opencv.org/question/14798/what-is-the-best-practise-for-passing-cvmats-around/)
2. How to Pass a cv::Mat across a network? - [link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8898442/10358768)

Answer (score 0):

Notice that the types are defined like this:

```
#define     CV_16S   3
```

I think you should pass an `int` (`or uint64_t`  as in OpenCV's source code):

```
yourFunction(rs2::frame fr, int mat_type)
```

And call the and call your function like:

```
yourFunction(fr, cv::CV_8SC1)
```

you can see the definitions [here](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d1/d1b/group__core__hal__interface.html) , and there's a cool easy to use matrix [here](https://gist.github.com/yangcha/38f2fa630e223a8546f9b48ebbb3e61a)

Then, in your function do a switch case:

```
switch(mat_type) {
    case cv::CV_8SC1 : //Something
    case cv::CV_32S : //Something else
.
.
.

}
```

Anyway you will have to do a case for every type ( which  is normal).
And don't forget the necesary includes to access `cv` wherever you use it

Comment: ... asuming the data type at compile-time

Answer (score 0):

If your question is "Don't you think runtime type-checking is a bit impractical and doesn't scale well when you handle more and more types?" then the answer is yes, but that's what you sign for when you use type-erased objects like cv::Mat.

FYI there's a `cv::Mat_<T>` type in OpenCV that you can use in case you know the data type at compile-time and don't want to lose that information.