# Is it in C++ standard to align such structures

Tags: c++, x86

Take this example

```
class A
{
public:
  int a; 
  char b;
  int c;
};
```

Every compiler (for x86, 32 or 64 bit) I see allocates 12 bytes for class `A`, instead of 9. So they are aligning `b` to the integer boundary or bus boundary you can say. My question is if this is in C++ standard to do so and if there are any compilers who does not do like that.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The C++ standard specifies that:

- objects have an alignment requirement of which their size is a multiple (so if `int` is 4 bytes wide, then it requires an alignment of 1, 2 or 4 bytes, depending on the implementation).
- member objects (if they are not separated by access specifiers such as `public`) are all allocated in the order they're declared
- and they are allocated respecting their alignment requirements.

So no, the standard doesn't say exactly that the class should have a size of 12 bytes.

But it *does* say that `b` should be allocated after `a`, and that `c` should be allocated after `b`.

On a platform where `int` is 4 bytes wide, and requires 4-byte alignment, this leaves 12 bytes as the smallest valid size:

- `a` takes the first 4 bytes
- `b` takes one byte
- `c` needs 4 bytes, *but* must be allocated on a 4-byte boundary. `b` ended one byte *past* such a boundary, so the next valid position to place `c` at is found by inserting 3 bytes of padding.

So the total size of the class ends up being the size of the members (4 + 1 + 4 = 9) plus three bytes of padding, for a total of 12.

There is another rule which has no effect here, but which would matter if you had defined the members in the order `a, c, b` instead.

The containing class (`A`) inherits the alignment requirement from the strictest-aligned member object. That is, because it contains an `int`, it has the same alignment requirement as an `int` does. And because the object's total size must be a multiple of its alignment requirement, a class containing the members in the order `a, b, c` would *still* require 12 bytes of storage. It'd just shift the 3 bytes of padding to the end of the class, instead of between `b` and `c`.

However, in some other cases, reordering members in descending order of size can *sometimes* reduce the size of a class.

Suppose we'd had a class like this instead:

```
class B {
  char a;
  double b;
  int c;
};
```

This would have required 24 bytes of storage (1 bytes for `a`, 8 byte for `b`, and 4 bytes for `c`, but then to ensure `b` ends up on an 8-byte boundary, we'd need *7* bytes of padding between `a` and `b`, and to ensure that the whole class ends up with a size that is a multiple of 8, we need another 4 bytes after `c`.

But reordering the members according to size, like this:

```
class B {
  double b;
  int c;
  char a;
};
```

results in a class requiring only 16 bytes:

the same 1 + 4 + 8 bytes for the member objects themselves, but now `c` is already aligned on a 4-byte boundary (because it comes after `b` which ends on an 8-byte boundary), and `a` never needs any alignment, so the only alignment we need is to ensure that `B` has a size that is a multiple of 8. The members take 13 bytes, so we can add 3 bytes of padding, and the class ends up at 16 bytes, 33% smaller than the first version.

Comment: You might also point out that on most architectures, accessing a mis-aligned object will result in some sort of a bus error, which will cause the program to crash.  On an Intel, the program won't crash, but it will still run a lot slower if the data is misaligned.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to control structure packing at compile-time, using pragma directives.
**[See #Pragma Pack](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2e70t5y1%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)**

For example, the following does not align the members, and places them right next to each other.

```
#pragma pack(push, 1)
struct A4
{
  char a;
  double b;
  char c;
};
#pragma pack(pop)
```

Example from **[here](http://vcfaq.mvps.org/lang/11.htm)**.

**[GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Structure_002dPacking-Pragmas.html)** also supports pragma pack. The directive isn't the part of some standard, but a lot of compilers do support it.

---

However, there shouldn't be a reason to do the above. The compiler aligns them to speed up access to members, and there should be **no reason to change that**.

Comment: But is it defined in C++ standard that the default case would to be to align to bus boundary.

Comment: [**GCC**](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Structure_002dPacking-Pragmas.html) supports a set of #pragma directives, but they support that because MS's compilers do as well. The `pack` directive isn't a part of any standard AFAIK.

Comment: In fact, `#pragma` _anything_ is by definition not part of any standard.

Comment: @user1018562 It's defined in C++ that an implementation can add padding pretty much where ever it wants, except at the beginning of a struct.  (In practice, of course, no implementation will add padding unless it feels it necessary, either to avoid crashing the program or, in the case of Intel, to avoid unnecessarily slowing the process down.)

Comment: *"There shouldn't be a reason to do the above"* There are use cases for this, such as [packing structures for network transport](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1593691/265575).

Answer (score 0):

Standard allows the compilers to padd more bytes if necessary. It basically depends on the architecture of the host rather than compiler.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, alignment is mentioned everywhere in the standard, mainly section 3.11 (*Alignment*). It is platform-dependent, so any program that depends on the actual size of an object is inherently non-portable.

Answer (score 0):

In your case 'b' is always correctly aligned. It's *padded* to align *c* in 32-bit boundaries. Even though there is some room for specific implementations, most compilers follow the rule of aligning 2 and 4-byte variables to 2 and 4 byte boundaries.

In 32-bit systems also doubles and long ints (8 bytes) are aligned to 4-byte boundaries, but aligned to 8-byte in 64-bit systems.

Comment: How the systems aligns different types is very implementation dependent.  I've used 32 bit systems where doubles were aligned on 8 byte boundaries, and I've seen all sorts of alignments for `long double`.

Comment: Well yes, maybe long double is pushing the limits of compatibility.