# send commands to client from server c++

Tags: c++, sockets

is there any way to send commands from server to client with c++?
i use send() function, but i have to convert numbers(like 0x100) to strings then convert strings to numbers in the client side...
Basically the function that send directly numbers to client...

server:

```
ZeroMemory(msg,sizeof(msg));
wsprintf( msg , "142");
send(connect_sock ,(char*) msg , sizeof(msg) , 0);
```

client:

```
ZeroMemory(msg,sizeof(msg));    
recv (connect_sock, msg, sizeof(msg)-1, 0);
int i = atoi(msg);
if ( i == 142 )
...
```

Comment: It all depends on the application protocol you're using.

Comment: You're receiving a string, because you send a string - you could send any block of data (e.g. a message struct) or encode a more verbose message as xml and send that as a string

Comment: well, so how change message struct to send integer instead?

Comment: instead of `char msg[MESSAGE_LENGTH];` create your own struct, and use `MyStruct msg;`    Note that this will cause you endian / size issues if your client and server are on different platforms

Comment: A better example is given here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1577161/passing-a-structure-through-sockets-in-c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple - you can't, but you can write your own, or you can find libraries where everything is done for you.

1) boost::asio (c++) has serialization example

2) libcli (c) for telnet protocol (https://github.com/dparrish/libcli)

3) libtpl (c) serialization (http://troydhanson.github.io/tpl/)

many more...

Example for raw descriptors (packing argv using libtpl):

connecting and creating serverFd on your own

```
tpl_node *tn;
char* bufferArgv;

/** @todo pass array or string? */
tn = tpl_map("iA(s)", &argc, &bufferArgv);
tpl_pack(tn, 0); 

char** _argv;
for (_argv = argv; *_argv != 0; _argv++)
{
    bufferArgv = *_argv;
    tpl_pack(tn, 1);
}

tpl_dump(tn, TPL_FD, serverFd);
tpl_free(tn);
```

Unpack

```
tpl_node *tn;
char* bufferArgv;
int argc;

tn = tpl_map("iA(s)", &argc, &bufferArgv);
tpl_load(tn, TPL_FD, serverFd);
tpl_unpack(tn, 0);
```

if you brave enough replace tpl_dump and tpl_load and send raw tn.data

Comment: is there any source code for send() and recv() functions? any link?

Comment: Why should you mess with send() and recv()?

Answer (score 0):

you can try like this , using the system function 
Server :

wsprintf( msg , "142");
send(connect_sock ,(char*) msg , sizeof(msg) , 0);

Client :

recv (connect_sock, msg, sizeof(msg)-1, 0);
string result = system( "./ %s", msg) ;

i am not sure abt the functionality . please check this and let me know .

Comment: it doesn't works... really there is not source code for remote desktop app , network games, and others. to let me know about architecture of net apps?