# Unknown Byte in C write struct

Tags: java, c, struct, arrays

I'm sending a c struct with write to a server. The struct and write look like this.

```
typedef struct MyStruct {
    uint8_t         flag; 
    char            str[50];
    int32_t         number;
    time_t          time; 

} MyStruct ;

...

// Create mystruct

memset(&mystruct->flag,   '\1', sizeof(uint8_t));
memset(&mystruct->str, '\0', sizeof(char) * 50);
memset(&mystruct->number, '\2', sizeof(int32_t)); 
memset(&mystruct->time,   '\3', sizeof(time_t)); 

write(sockfd, mystruct, sizeof(MyStruct));
```

The server, in Java, receives the information in a nio `ByteBuffer` and then gets a `byte[]` with `ByteBuffer.array`. When I examine the `byte[]` its contents are:

```
[ 0]         = 1
[ 1] to [50] = 0
[51]         = 70
[52] to [55] = 2
[56] to [63] = 3
```

If you add the lengths up 1 + 50 + 4 + 8 you get 63, but the length with the odd 70 byte is 64.

Why is the 70 byte here? Does it have something to do with networking or c structs? Also how, if I can, get rid of it?

Comment: Please just don't do this. You're asking for a world of pain. If you're going to use a channel that sends streams of bytes, define precisely what the stream of bytes you're going to exchange is. Don't say "I'll send whatever the C struct happens to be and hope it happens to make sense to the other side".

Comment: Aside, do you realise that `memset(&mystruct->number, '\2', sizeof(int32_t));` sets the variable to `0x02020202`, or decimal `33686018`?

Comment: @WeatherVane yes, this is just me debugging it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why is the 70 byte here? Does it have something to do with networking
>   or c structs? Also how, if I can, get rid of it?

It probably has to do with structure [padding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4306186/structure-padding-and-packing). You can try and serialize each member of the structure separately if that's the case.

Also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1577161/passing-a-structure-through-sockets-in-c) is a post which well explains all the pitfalls with serialization in C.

Serialization in C is more tricky than say in C# or I think also in Java, for example in C# you know that integer is always 4 bytes in size, which is not the case in C, where the size of integer can vary on platforms.

Comment: So by serialize, in C, I should make a method that creates a byte array set the way I want to?

Comment: @ezPaint Yes check the link in my answer

Comment: @ezPaint There is also smth like pragma pack - but often it is advised against

Answer (score 2):

It's almost certainly due to structure padding; most likely, your compiler/processor requires 32-bit values to be 32-bit aligned, so since your `uint8_t` and your `char[50]` add up to 51 bytes, there's a one-byte pad between `str` and `number`.

As was mentioned in the comments - you really want to handle your serialization explicitly.  There are a number of libraries that can handle defining Java and C/C++ types, along with methods to serialize/deserialize in each language.