# what is the best way to pack and unpack messages to send/receive them trough the network like in a mmo game?

Tags: sockets, networking, mmo

What is the best way to send information messages like: position, healt to server and then broadcast them to all the players (how to "pack" and "unpack" them in a good and fast way?)

i have a message system that manages structs (messages) like:

```
struct position{
    long entityId;
    float x;
    float y;
    float z;
};
```

and now, i need to "pack" this structs (i can change this structs to any other suggestion) in a fast way to send them to the server (through the network) and then "unpack" them in the client side.

I'm interested in how mmo game's do that.

Thanks!

Comment: The thing you're looking for is (de)serialization.  You can do it by hand if you want to, but if you'd like a ready-made solution, Google's Protocol Buffers library is well-regarded:  https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/

Comment: thankyou yes, i know.. but how to do the deserialisation of an struct like above in a fast way without using external libraries?

Comment: There are about a jillion questions about that on this site.  Why don't you type [serialization] into the search box here and read some of them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Variable types that may make use of a FPU and may contain a different *memory representation* [not only byte order] on different architectures (such as `float` and `double`) should never be used in network transfers if the architecture of both ends cannot be known (or, in other words, is **not** granted to be a specific architecture).

A `float` type **representation** may conform to [IEEE 754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point) specification in one architecture, but it's not granted that every architecture complies to it. Always make use of types whose sizes are well-known (such as `uint16_t`, `uint32_t`, etc. from `stdint.h`) and make use of `htons()` / `ntohs()` / `htonl()` / `ntohl()` (from `arpa/inet.h`) to convert from **host byte order** to **network byte order** and vice-versa.

You'll also need to make use of compiler extensions to grant alignments (such as `__attribute__ ((align()))`, or `#pragma pack()`) to grant that the structure alignment is the same on both ends.

If you don't want [or cannot make use of] compiler extensions (due to portability issues), then structs are not the [direct] way to go.

In that case, you can still use structures in your code, but you should implement custom serialization / unserialization routines in order to build a buffer to be transmitted (also accounting for host to network and network to host byte order and never making use of `float` / `double` types [FPU] **unless you cover these conversions in you serialization routines**).

Also, take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1577161/passing-a-structure-through-sockets-in-c), and read **all** the answers from it with positive vote rating (I only have to add to it that you should only use `stdint.h` types when dealing with network communications).

Comment: thankyou very much.

Comment: @user2303826 yw :)