# Each deserialized 64 bit integer number should be converted to bit wise equivalent 64 bit floating number

Tags: c++, serialization, floating-point, deserialization, bitwise-operators

I have above statement in file I am refering . Expected output is double. I could not find anything relevant to my problem.
I found this 
[Passing a structure through Sockets in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1577161/passing-a-structure-through-sockets-in-c)
but dont know if its relevant.
I am not reading that int64 value. I am getting it from other process and that is the way it is designed.

Does anyone have any theory about serialization and deserialization of ints?

Comment: Why don't you read the data directly into a `double`?

Comment: std::memcpy will do it for you. union of int64 and float is UB,

Comment: Thanks Nathan for update.I am not reading that one. I am getting it from other process and that is the way it is designed.

Comment: @RichardCritten void * comp = &(x_double);
   double component = (*(F64 *)comp); i guess this does the same it did not work

Comment: Is also UB.  memcpy is now the only standard defined way of copying data between different types (iirc there are few edge cases with char / unsigned char).

Comment: If it didn't work, what was the expected output and what did you get? Is it just the old endianness problem?

Answer (score 1):

There is exactly one defined way to bitwise-copy one type into another in c++ - `memcpy`.

```
template<class Out, class In, std::enable_if_t<(sizeof(In) == sizeof(Out))>* = nullptr>
Out mangle(const In& in)
{
    Out result;
    std::memcpy(std::addressof(result), std::addressof(in), sizeof(Out));
    return result;
}


int main()
{
    double a = 1.1;
    auto b = mangle<std::uint64_t>(a);
    auto c = mangle<double>(b);

    std::cout << a << " " << std::hex << b << " " << c << std::endl;
}
```

example output:

```
1.1 3ff199999999999a 1.1
```

Comment: void * comp = &(x_double); double component = (*(F64 *)comp); I get the same answer which is not corerct. but thanks for your help

Comment: you may well get the same answer, but the behaviour when using c-style casts is not defined by the standard

Answer (score -3):

How about reading that 64-bit number and using reinterpret_cast to convert it to bitwise equivalent floating point number.

```
int64_t a = 121314;
double b = *reinterpret_cast<double*>(&a);
int64_t c = *reinterpret_cast<int64_t*>(&b);
assert(a==c);
```

Comment: thanks but it  does not build error C2440: 'reinterpret_cast': cannot convert from 'int64_t' to 'double'