# Sending struct over tcp socket in C++

Tags: c++, sockets, tcp, send, recv

I am trying to send struct over tcp socket. I am a newbie in socket programming, I did try the options suggested here already but those did not serve my purpose. Could someone pls help?

I have written Server.cpp and Client.cpp and both are compiling properly. However, when I am executing my Server to listen to the Client, I am not sure if the Server is able to recieve the structure from Client or not. Also, how can I read this structure once it is received?

Server.cpp

```
#include<iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<sys/types.h>
#include<sys/socket.h>
#include<netinet/in.h>
#include<string>
#include<stdio.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
        struct UE
        {
        string Net;
        int imsi;
        } ;
        UE UE2;
        //cout<<UE1.imsi<<"\n"<<UE1.Net<<"\n";
        int sock, cli, receive;
        sockaddr_in server, client;
        unsigned int len;

        if((sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) == -1)
        {
                perror("Socket:");
                exit(-1);
        }
        server.sin_family = AF_INET;
        server.sin_port = htons(10000);
        //cout<<htons(10000);
        server.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
        //cout<<INADDR_ANY;
        memset(&(server.sin_zero), '\0', 8);
        len = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);
        if((bind(sock, (struct sockaddr *)&server, len)) == -1)
        {
                perror("Bind:");
                exit(-1);

        }
        if((listen(sock, 5)) == -1)
        {
                perror("Listen:");
                exit(-1);
        }
        while(1)
        {
                cli = accept(sock,(struct sockaddr *)&client, &len);
                if(cli == -1)
                {
                        perror("Accept");
                        exit(-1);
                }
                receive = recv(sock, (void*)&UE2, sizeof(UE2), NULL);
                cout<<UE2.imsi;
                //cout<<UE2.imsi<<"\n"<<UE2.Net;
                //int sent = send(cli, (const void*)&mesg, sizeof mesg, 0);
                //cout<<"Sent"<<sent<<" bytes to client :<<inet_ntoa(client.sin_addr)";
                close(cli);
        }
}
```

Client.cpp

```
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include<iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<sys/types.h>
#include<sys/socket.h>
#include<netinet/in.h>
#include<string>
#include<stdio.h>
using namespace std;
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
        struct UE
        {
        string Net;
        int imsi;
        } ;
        UE UE1;
        UE1.Net = "4G";
        UE1.imsi = htons(8649);
        int sock, receive;
        struct sockaddr_in server;
        char mesg[200];
        if((sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) == -1)
        {
                perror("Socket:");
                exit(-1);
        }
        server.sin_family = AF_INET;
        server.sin_port = htons(atoi(argv[2]));
        //cout<<server.sin.port;
        server.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(argv[1]);
        //cout<<server.sin_addr.s_addr;
        memset(&(server.sin_zero), '\0', 8);
        if(connect(sock, (struct sockaddr*)&server, sizeof(server)) == -1)
        {
                perror("Connect:");
                exit(-1);
        }
        int count = 0;
        while(count = 0)
        {
        send(sock, &UE1, sizeof(UE1), 0);
        //receive = recv(sock, (void*)&mesg, sizeof mesg, NULL);
        count++;
        }
        cout<<"Sent "<<UE1.imsi<<" and "<<UE1.Net<<" to Server \n";
        close(sock);
}
```

Comment: `struct UE` is of non-POD type (due to containing of `std::string`), hence it can't be sent by plain `send`/`recv` calls, in the manner that you attempt.

Comment: Could you pls elaborate as to how it can be done? :S

Comment: You really ought to avoid `using namespace std` - it is a bad habit to get into, and [can silently change the meaning of your program](/q/1452721) when you're not expecting it.  Get used to using the namespace prefix (`std` is intentionally very short), or importing *just the names you need* into the *smallest reasonable scope*.

Answer (score 4):

There are at least 2 problems in your code:

1. You cannot send objects like `std::string` and anything that contains it this way (formally non-POD data), you need to marshall your data. There are plenty of libraries around (like google proto buffers) or you can write your own. This topic is too wide to cover it in the answer here.
2. You cannot expect that you receive data from TCP stream by the same chunk you sent it, you must write code that can handle receiving data by pieces (and send it that way as well).

Comment: Also, even sending POD data is problematic, in that the byte-layout of the POD data can vary depending on the architecture of the CPU the program was compiled for.  When the struct's byte-layout and endianness (as specified by the compiler of the receiving program) don't exactly match those of the program running on the sender, the data will be misinterpreted by the receiver.

Answer (score 3):

You should never ever write a whole struct to a file or a socket. 
Always write each field separately, and read them the same way. 
When doing it this way you pay some memory overhead, but it's generally a good design for performance reasons because you don't want to do a write of each value to the socket.

When sending binary data you should always take care for the following things:

- Different [endianness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness)
- Different [padding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_structure_alignment#Data_Structure_Padding)
- Differences in the [bye-sizes of intrinsic types](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word_(computer_architecture)#Table_of_word_sizes)

You need some functions like the following:

```
virtual MESSAGE_BUFFER * GetMessageAsBinaryPtr()
{
  MESSAGE_BUFFER * binaryMsg = new MESSAGE_BUFFER;
  UINT8 * ptrBuffer = &(*binaryMsg)[0];
  ptrBuffer = this->serializeUInt16(ptrBuffer, this->m_majorVersion);
  ptrBuffer = this->serializeUInt16(ptrBuffer, this->m_minorVersion);
  ptrBuffer = this->serializeUInt32(ptrBuffer,         (UINT32)this->m_messageType);
  ptrBuffer = this->serializeUInt64(ptrBuffer, this->m_packetID);
  ptrBuffer = this->serializeDouble(ptrBuffer, this->m_timestamp);
  return binaryMsg;
}

virtual void CreateFromBinary(MESSAGE_BUFFER buffer)
{
  UINT8 * ptrBuffer = &buffer[0];
  ptrBuffer = this->deserializeUInt16FromBuffer(ptrBuffer, &this->m_majorVersion);
  ptrBuffer = this->deserializeUInt16FromBuffer(ptrBuffer, &this->m_minorVersion);

  UINT32 messageType = 0;
  ptrBuffer = this->deserializeUInt32FromBuffer(ptrBuffer, &messageType);
  this->SetMessageType((MessageTypes)messageType);

  ptrBuffer = this->deserializeUInt64FromBuffer(ptrBuffer, &this->m_packetID);
  ptrBuffer = this->deserializeDoubleFromBuffer(ptrBuffer, &this->m_timestamp);
}

inline UINT8 * serializeUInt16(UINT8 * buffer, UINT16 value)
{
  buffer[1] = value;
  buffer[0] = value >> 8;
  return buffer + 2;
}

inline UINT8 * deserializeUInt16FromBuffer(UINT8 * buffer, UINT16 *     pOutput)
{
  *pOutput = (*pOutput << 8) + buffer[0];
  *pOutput = (*pOutput << 8) + buffer[1];
  return buffer + 2;
}
```

When you have such functions you can serialize and deserialize your structs to a buffer and then send this buffer over your socket.

A few points to note:

- The struct to send is first serialized, field by field into a buffer
- MESSAGE_BUFFER is of type UINT8[1024]
- The serialization routine returns a pointer to the next free byte in the buffer, which we use to compute how many bytes it serialized to
- Theres no protection against buffer overflows in my routines

Comment: Taken from this SO answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/1577174/8033062

Answer (score 1):

There are few bugs in your code.
In server.cpp
`sockaddr_in`  --> `struct sockaddr_in`

Once connection request is accepted by `server` using `accept()` call, it returns **new file descriptor**, with that **new fd** you should do `read` and `write` operation not with old one.

Replace below statement

```
receive = recv(sock, (void*)&UE2, sizeof(UE2), NULL); /** you are receiving with old fd called sock **/
```

with

```
receive = recv(cli, (void*)&UE2, sizeof(UE2), NULL);
```

**client.cpp**

```
using namespace std;
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
        struct UE
        {
                string Net;
                int imsi;
        } ;
        UE UE1;
        UE1.Net = "4G";
        UE1.imsi = htons(8649);
        int sock, receive;
        struct sockaddr_in server;
        char mesg[200];
        sock = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
        perror("Socket:");

        server.sin_family = AF_INET;
        server.sin_port = htons(atoi(argv[2]));
        server.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(argv[1]);
        memset(&(server.sin_zero), '\0', 8);

        connect(sock, (struct sockaddr*)&server, sizeof(server));
        perror("Connect:");

        int count = 0;
        send(sock, &UE1, sizeof(UE1), 0);
        perror("send");
        cout<<"Sent "<<UE1.imsi<<" and "<<UE1.Net<<" to Server \n";
        close(sock);
}
```

**server.cpp**

```
using namespace std;
int main()
{
        struct UE
        {
                string Net;
                int imsi;
        } ;
        UE UE2;

        int sock, cli, receive;
        struct sockaddr_in server, client;
        unsigned int len;
        sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
        perror("Socket:");

        server.sin_family = AF_INET;
        server.sin_port = htons(10001);
        server.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
        memset(&(server.sin_zero), '\0', 8);

        len = sizeof(server);
        bind(sock, (struct sockaddr *)&server, len);
        perror("Bind:");

        listen(sock, 1);
        perror("Listen:");

        cli = accept(sock,(struct sockaddr *)&client, &len);
        perror("accept");
        receive = recv(cli, ( void*)&UE2, sizeof(UE2), 0);
        perror("recv");

        cout << "rec = "<<receive<<endl;
        cout<<UE2.imsi<<"\n";
        close(sock);
        perror("close");
}
```

Comment: Your code does not work too. Std::string cannot be transferred inside a struct